# Creating SEO friendly URLs in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, custom-routes

I currently have URLs which look like this:

```
things?category_id=6&country_id=17
```

and I would like to have URLs which look like this:

```
/printer_cartridges/united_kingdom
```

Is there a way in Rails 3, without hard coding all of the categories and countries in the router to have the URLs as I would like above, perhaps using `find_by_name` or the such like? What is the best way to approach this?

Comment: Read the Rails Guide on routing, especially Nested Resources:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
match '/:category_slug/:country_slug', :to => 'things#index'
```

Then you'll need to update your action to look up everything using params[:category_slug] and params[:country_slug] instead of the ids. Look at the [slugged gem](https://github.com/Sutto/slugged) to generate slugs.

Comment: Sutto's slugged gem is the way to go on this. Thanks Jordan.

Answer (score 3):

In your category model add the method

```
def to_param
   "#{category_name.parameterize}/#{location_name.parameterize}"
end
```

where category_name and location_name are where you input where you have have the names stored.