# How to user defined friendly URLs in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, friendly-url, friendly-id

Now i have something like this

```
http://myapp.com/pages/1
http://myapp.com/pages/2
http://myapp.com/pages/3
http://myapp.com/pages/4
```

And each page belong to one `user`

What i need is to each user to set it's own custom name for the page.

I was thinking of using the `friendly_id` gem http://norman.github.com/friendly_id/
but I don't find any method to directly edit the slug to set a custom friendly url

how should i proceed?

Comment: Please look at this other post:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4995759/creating-seo-friendly-urls-in-rails-3][1]

Hope that helps,

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4995759/creating-seo-friendly-urls-in-rails-3

Answer (score 3):

FriendlyID is a great gem.

It shouldn't be hard to implement user defined page URL.
Create table `pages` with `user_id` and `link`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pages

class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  has_friendly_id :link # link is name of the column whose value will be replaced by slugged value
```

On the `page#new` you add an input for the `link` attribute.

Alternatively, you could set friendly_id on title or something else with :use_slug => true option. This way FriendlyID will take the title and modify it so it doesn't have and restricted characters. It will use it's own table to store slugs. Use `cached_slug` to increase performanse.

Updated

To give users a choice whether they wan't to set a custom link, you could do this:

1. Set friendly_id on the `link` field without slugs..
2. Make a virtual attribute `permalink` so you could show it in your forms.
3. In the before_filter, check whether the `permalink` is set.
4. If it is, write it to the `link` field.
5. If it's not, write title to the `link` field.

FriendlyID uses `babosa` gem to generate slugs. If you decide to use it as well, this is how your filter could look like:

```
protected
  def generate_link
                #you might need to use .nil? instead
    self.link = self.permalink.empty? ? make_slug(self.title) : make_slug(self.permalink)
  end

  def make_slug(value)
    value.to_slug.normalize.to_s #you could as well use ph6py's way
  end
```

Comment: But what if i want to keep it in one field where i have the `title` field for the page.... I may use `has_friendly_id :title` then i can go to to the page using the friendly_id based on the title but i want to give a second option... something like `custom_link` so when the user sets some value there it takes first the `custom_link` instead of the `friendly_id` if the user wants something custom but the title of the page in the `URL` would that be a good way to go? what do you think?

Answer (score 2):

Adding to_param method to one of the models should help:

```
def to_param
  "#{id}-#{call_to_method_that_returns_custom_name.parameterize}"
end
```

Hope this is what you are looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not using the friendly_url gem and am not sure whether my way is efficient. But it works fine for me.

I have a model called `Node` with `id` and friendly url field called `url_title`.

My `routes.rb` file:

```
resource 'nodes/:url_title', :to => 'Nodes#view'
```

`nodes_controller.rb`

```
class NodesController <ActiveController
 def view
  @node = Node.find_by_url_title(:params(url_title))
 end
end
```

And use the `@node` variable to populate your view.

Now, whenever I type www.example.com/nodes/awesome-title  , it takes me to the proper page. One argument against this can be need to create an index on a non-primary field. But I think that might be required for better performance even in the friendly_url gem. Also, the non-primary field `url_title` needs to be unique. Again, this might be required even for correct working for `friendly_url` .
Feel free to correct me if I am wrong in these assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of ways, you can achieve this-

1) using Stringex

2) sluggable-finder

3) friendly_id

A complete step by step methodology with reasons for each to be used can be found out [here](http://doblock.com/articles/seo-friendly-urls-for-your-rails-app-with-friendly_id). Happy reading!